# i want to show all record of one Custom listLiew to another Custom ListView on Button Click Event

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created two Custom listView,both have two textView and one EditText ,I want to show all record which is entered in edittext accept textView on second Custom ListView but when i click on button to get record, it show only last record in second  Custom listView!

[image]

```
public class Mmnue extends Activity {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList;
String rate ;
String name ;
String quant;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menuitem);
    final ListView lisView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    final ListView lisView2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);


    MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    HashMap<String, String> map;

    /*** Rows 1 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Butterscotch");
    map.put("Code", "Rs 10");
    MyArrList.add(map);

    /*** Rows 2 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Birthday Cake");
    map.put("Code", "Rs 100");
    MyArrList.add(map);

    /*** Rows 3 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Black  Crunch");
    map.put("Code", "Rs 102");
    MyArrList.add(map);

    /*** Rows 4 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Industrial Chocolate");
    map.put("Code", "Rs 200");
    MyArrList.add(map);

    /*** Rows 5 ***/
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("ID", "Coffee Molasses Chip");
    map.put("Code", " Rs 500");
    MyArrList.add(map);    




    lisView1.setAdapter(new CountryAdapter(this));






    Button btnGetItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetItem);
    btnGetItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {


    int count = lisView1.getAdapter().getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)lisView1.getChildAt(i); // Find by under   LinearLayout
    TextView itemname = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.nm);

    TextView rat = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.rat);

    EditText quan = (EditText)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.txtInput);

    rate = rat.getText().toString();
     quant = quan.getText().toString();
     name = itemname.getText().toString();

    Toast.makeText(Mmnue.this,name + ", " + rate+ " , " +quant   ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    lisView2.setAdapter(new CountryAdapter2(getApplicationContext()));

    }




    }
    });



    }


    public class CountryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
    private Context context;

    public CountryAdapter(Context c)
    {
    //super( c, R.layout.activity_column, R.id.rowTextView, );
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    context = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return MyArrList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mmnue, null);

    }

    // ColID
    TextView txtID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nm);

    txtID.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("ID") +".");

    // ColCode
    TextView txtCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rat);
    txtCode.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("Code"));


    return convertView;

    }

    }

    public class CountryAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter
    {
    private Context context;

    public CountryAdapter2(Context c)
    {
    //super( c, R.layout.activity_column, R.id.rowTextView, );
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    context = c;
    }


    public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return MyArrList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_mmnue, null);

    }

    // ColID
    TextView txtID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nm);
    //txtID.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("ID") +".");
    txtID.setText(name);
    // ColCode
    TextView txtCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rat);
//  txtCode.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("Code"));
    txtCode.setText(rate);

    EditText quan = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
//  txtCode.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("Code"));
    quan.setText(quant);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+quant+""+rate+""+name,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return convertView;

    }

    }
```

Comment: new bie to android i think..?try it, may take some time to do this. not a standard question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but it seems like you want the same datathat's exposed in ListView1 to be copied to ListView2.  Since ListViews are backed by Adapters, and yours is the CountryAdapter, in it there's an ArrayList. You can add a method called `public ArrayList getData()` that returns your ArrayList so that you can populate ListView2.

Comment: no i want to show updated data to the  second list view, I men that when i enter the value to the editText of first ListView and then click on button to get record and show that updation to second listView

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you store name, quant, and rate in a variable that will be overwritten each time you go through the loop. To solve this, you could consider storing all the values in arrays and then once you have the entire array of data, then you update the second listView.

**Your problem spot**

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)lisView1.getChildAt(i); // Find by under   LinearLayout
    TextView itemname = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.nm);

    TextView rat = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.rat);

    EditText quan = (EditText)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.txtInput);

    rate = rat.getText().toString();
     quant = quan.getText().toString();
     name = itemname.getText().toString();
```

**One solution**

```
String rate[count], quant[count], name[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)lisView1.getChildAt(i); // Find by under   LinearLayout
        TextView itemname = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.nm);

        TextView rat = (TextView)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.rat);

        EditText quan = (EditText)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.txtInput);

        rate[i] = rat.getText().toString();
         quant[i] = quan.getText().toString();
         name[i] = itemname.getText().toString();
```

On the button click, change the data set and use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the listView

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Change ListView Data Set
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });
```